# Change label in Query ImportRange for a sum using 2 of the columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've managed to create a QUERY that includes a sum to calculate the difference between BUDGET (Col3) and ACTUAL (Col4) and I've relabelled them respectively with those names however, the calculation still shows the query default header - below is my query

=query(importrange("1rDDsD671JFvpnNOdqjNPoP26fvMjriXEq9AO2gy0","2. WP Cost Details!C:F"),"Select Col2, sum(Col3), sum(Col4), sum(Col3)-sum(Col4)
WHERE Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1
label sum(Col3) 'Budget',sum(Col4) 'Actual'")

I tried including sum(Col3) - sum(Col4) 'Difference' at the end of the label line but it didn't work

Is this even possible and if so, what have I done wrong?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

`=query(importrange("1rDDsD671JFvpnNOdqjNPoP26fvMjriXEq9AO2gy0","2. WP Cost Details!C:F"),"Select Col2, sum(Col3), sum(Col4), sum(Col3)-sum(Col4) WHERE Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1 label sum(Col3) 'Budget',sum(Col4) 'Actual', sum(Col3)-sum(Col4) 'Difference'")`

Comment: Thank you so much.. I'm almost certain I tried that but I must've put the punctuation in the wrong place or misspelled one of the fields